# Como comprobar el contenido de readValue

Tags: java, json, jackson

vereis estoy trasteando un poco con la API de la NBA y tengo este json en concreto

https://data.nba.com/data/10s/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2017/league/00_full_schedule_week.json

Entonces yo tengo una clase Parser

```
public class Parser {

    private Map<String, Object> otherProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
            otherProperties.put(name, value);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parser{" +
                ", otherProperties=" + otherProperties +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Seguido de un main que me funciona correctamente y me muestra en pantalla el contenido de ese fichero json.

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Parser car = mapper.readValue(new File("full_schedule.json"), Parser.class);

        System.out.println(car);

    }
```

Quiero saber si hay una manera de comprobar el valor que devuelve el json , no mostrar la cadena completa en sí , si no saber si hay alguna forma de iterar esta propiedad.

Comment: Creo que me ha quedado todo claro menos la pregunta final, ¿puedes repasar tu últimas dos líneas?

Comment: La he intentado revisar .. a ver ahora @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0):

No sé exactamente qué es lo que no te queda claro, pero voy a intentar explicar lo que veo y qué opciones tienes:

Has creado un objeto Parser que contiene una instancia de Map, guardando todo el JSON.

Primero vamos a modificar un poco tu código:

```
public class Parser {

    private Map<String, Object> otherProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        otherProperties.put(name, value);

    }
    public Object get(String key) {
        return this.otherProperties.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parser{" + ", otherProperties=" + otherProperties + '}';
    }
}
```

Ahora puedes "navegar" por los valores del JSON. Puesto que el elemento `lscd` era una lista de elementos, en Java pasa a ser un List, y en la primera posición tendremos un objeto (de nuevo "mapeado" a un Map cuya clave es "mscd"). Puedes obtener los nombres de los meses así:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream data = Parser.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.json");
        Parser car = mapper.readValue(data, Parser.class);
        List<Map<String,Object>> lscd=(List<Map<String,Object>>) car.get("lscd");
        for (Map<String,Object> item: lscd) {
            Map<String,Object> month=(Map<String, Object>) item.get("mscd");
            System.out.println(month.get("mon"));
        }
    }
```

Es bastante farragoso, pero en general la regla es que si en el JSON el valor empieza por:

- Llave `{` : es un Map
- Corchete `[` : Es un List
- Comillas `"` : Es un String
- Un número: Es un número, mejor prueba a usar double o BigDecimal si crees que puede tener decimales.

Comment: Vas bien , ahora lo pruebo gracias :)